# deleteval() for BinaryHeap c++

Tags: c++

How can I write a deleteval() function in c++ which deletes the value in a Binary Heap. Im not sure how to traverse through the vector and and what function to use to delete the value. Any ideas? Also my attempt is below.

```
template <typename Comparable>
void BinaryHeap<Comparable>::deleteVal(int p, Comparable &val)
{
    //int remove = array[val];
    array.erase(array.begin()+val);

}
```

Comment: We'd need a complete, minimal, working example to be able to help better. What is `p` for, what is the interface expected of `Comparable`? Why is `val` passed by reference? How do you communicate it back to client code when the value is not found?

Comment: @zyndor p is the node reference and val is the value stored in the node. For example

Comment: 3 4 5 6 7 8 is the vector. deleting at index 3 would delete 6 i believe.

Comment: It looks like you have an array-backed heap, which means that you don't need a 'node' type with pointers to parent / children: you can take advantage of the fact that for an element at index `i`, the elements at `i * 2` and `(i * 2) + 1` will be the children.